# update from SSL 3.0 to TLS Paypal

Tags: paypal

not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question, but I received an email from paypal today

I own a ecommerce site in the UK

Is this a major technical job for my webmaster to do, ie charging me a huge bill for work that wasnt my fault. Please advise. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the [POODLE Attack Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) that is causing SSLv3 versions to bleed sensitive information. This was discovered in September 2014, and has affected almost all technological companies.

For this reason, PayPal has disabled SSLv3 encryption, and have led everyone to upgrade their system to use a newer version of TLSv1 encryption.

I cannot answer the need for a major technological job, however, the need is to simply update the system to the latest versions, or follow instructions provided here at https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182